# Casting error in VB 4.5 when turning Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5

The following code works great with Option Strict off.  However flipping the switch to On gives me the following error - ***Value of type DSreprint_ship.companyRow cannot be converted to DSholding.companyRow***.  on Me.DSreprint_ship.company

```
Dim row As DSholding.companyRow
    For Each row In Me.DSreprint_ship.company
        If row.PLANT = Me.DSreprint_ship.shipmaster.Item(0).plant Then
            If row.IsCITYNull Then
                From_city = "null"
            Else
                From_city = row.CITY
            End If
            If row.IsSTATENull Then
                From_state = "null"
            Else
                From_state = row.STATE
            End If

        End If
    Next
```

I've researched this until I'm blue in the face and can't seem to see the issue.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `DSreprint_ship.company` a list of `DSholding.companyRow` objects?

Comment: ...and does `Me.DSreprint_ship.company` actually contain/represent a collection of `DSholding.companyRow` items?

Comment: To both Karl and Plutonix - Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using two different row types.  They `DSreprent_ship.companyRow` is different than DSHolding.companyRow` type.  Change the declaration of row to the following

```
Dim row As DSreprint_ship.companyRow
```